# I need to iterate through a table of weight values and determine if each weight is valid

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I need to determine whether weights in a table are valid. This table has five columns: User_ID, Activity_ID, Activity_DT, Weight, and Weight_Source. The query output needs to include a calculated column called Valid_Weight. The first row for every user should mark the Valid_Weight column to 1. A 1 in the Valid_Weight column indicates that a weight is valid. A weight is considered valid if there is less than a 5% change between the current weight and the last weight in which the Valid_Weight column has a 1 in it. If the weight is considered as valid, then the Valid_Weight column will be marked with a 1.  If the weight is considered as invalid, then the Valid_Weight column will be marked with a 0. The current row's weight cannot evaluate against a previous row that has 0 in the Valid_Weight column and has to evaluate against the latest row with a 1 in the Valid Weight column.

I have been trying to use a recursive cte, but it keeps failing due to hitting the max_recursion_rows limit. I think that my code is producing an infinite loop.

I just need to know the most efficient way to evaluate all of the rows in the table.

Here is what the result should look like:

| Activity_ID | User_ID | Activity_DT | Weight | Weight_Source | Valid Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 56 | 2017-04-19 | 163 | clinic | 1 |
| 2 | 56 | 2017-04-25 | 163.80 | home_scale | 1 |
| 3 | 56 | 2017-04-27 | 164.46 | home_scale | 1 |
| 4 | 56 | 2017-05-11 | 85.32 | home_scale | 0 |
| 5 | 56 | 2017-05-12 | 190.26 | home_scale | 0 |
| 6 | 56 | 2017-05-20 | 166.45 | home_scale | 1 |
| 7 | 56 | 2017-05-21 | 191.14 | home_scale | 0 |
| 8 | 56 | 2017-06-09 | 159.17 | home_scale | 1 |
| 9 | 56 | 2017-06-10 | 160.94 | home_scale | 1 |

Here is the recursive CTE code I have been trying to use for reference:

```
WITH    RECURSIVE   cteValWgt(User_ID, Activity_ID, Activity_DT, Weight, Weight_Source, Valid_Weight)
        
AS      (SELECT comb.User_ID,
                comb.Activity_ID,
                comb.Activity_DT,
                comb.Weight,
                comb.Weight_Source,
                1 AS Valid_Weight
                
         FROM   etl.rdm_weight_validation AS COMB
         
         WHERE  comb.ROW# = 1
         
        UNION ALL
        
         SELECT comb.User_ID,
                comb.Activity_ID,
                comb.Activity_DT,
                comb.Weight,
                comb.Weight_Source,
                CASE    WHEN ABS(comb.Weight - vw.Weight)/(vw.Weight) <= 0.05 THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                END AS Valid_Weight
                
         FROM   cteValWgt AS VW
                INNER JOIN  etl.rdm_weight_validation AS comb
                            ON  vw.User_ID = comb.User_ID
                                AND
                                vw.Activity_DT < comb.Activity_DT
                                AND
                                vw.Valid_Weight = 1)

SELECT  vw.User_ID,
        vw.Activity_ID,
        vw.Activity_DT,
        vw.Weight,
        vw.Weight_Source,
        vw.Valid_Weight

FROM    cteValWgt AS VW

ORDER BY vw.User_ID, vw.Activity_DT
```

Comment: Update your post with sample data and expected output. It'll help people further understand what you're attempting to do.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out lemon! I have updated the submission with how the data should look.

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Comment: Removed image and replaced with table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query does not seem to actually iterate over the dataset; the anchor is filtered on `ROW# = 1`, but this column does not come into play in the recursion, where the join conditions from the CTE to the data table do not look right.

In absence of an existing sequencing column, we can start by enumerating the records with `row_number()`, so we can then use this information to efficiently walk from one record to the next.

Also, we can optimize the query by keeping track of the last valid weight that we met, so the comparison with the current weight is straight forward, using `case` expressions.

Here is one way to phrase the query:

```
with recursive 
    -- enumerate the dataset for each user
    data as (
        select t.*, 
            row_number() over(partition by user_id order by activity_id) rn
        from mytable t 
    ),
    -- recursive CTE
    rcte (activity_id, user_id, activity_dt, weight, weight_source, rn, weight_is_valid, last_valid_weight) as (
        -- anchor : first row per user
        select activity_id, user_id, activity_dt, weight, weight_source, rn, 1, weight
        from data
        where rn = 1
        union all
        -- recursion
        select d.activity_id, d.user_id, d.activity_dt, d.weight, d.weight_source, d.rn,
            -- conditional expressions to assess the validity of the weight
            case when abs( d.weight - r.last_valid_weight ) / r.last_valid_weight <= 0.05 then 1 else 0 end,
            case when abs( d.weight - r.last_valid_weight ) / r.last_valid_weight <= 0.05 then d.weight else r.last_valid_weight end
        from rcte r
        -- join to bring the "next" user row
        inner join data d on d.user_id = r.user_id and d.rn = r.rn + 1
    )
select * from rcte
```

| activity_id | user_id | activity_dt | weight | weight_source | rn | weight_is_valid | last_valid_weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 56 | 2017-04-19 | 163.00 | clinic | 1 | 1 | 163.00 |
| 2 | 56 | 2017-04-25 | 163.80 | home_scale | 2 | 1 | 163.80 |
| 3 | 56 | 2017-04-27 | 164.46 | home_scale | 3 | 1 | 164.46 |
| 4 | 56 | 2017-05-11 | 85.32 | home_scale | 4 | 0 | 164.46 |
| 5 | 56 | 2017-05-12 | 190.26 | home_scale | 5 | 0 | 164.46 |
| 6 | 56 | 2017-05-20 | 166.45 | home_scale | 6 | 1 | 166.45 |
| 7 | 56 | 2017-05-21 | 191.14 | home_scale | 7 | 0 | 166.45 |
| 8 | 56 | 2017-06-09 | 159.17 | home_scale | 8 | 1 | 159.17 |
| 9 | 56 | 2017-06-10 | 160.94 | home_scale | 9 | 1 | 160.94 |

**[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PBuZ_B1x)**

Comment: This worked perfectly. I knew it was something small that I was missing. Thank you for the extra column to optimize the query!